# How to send post request from Android to a C# web API

Tags: c#, android, android-studio, asp.net-web-api, android-volley

As my question states, I have a c# web API (MVC.NET web API 2) with a controller having a POST method that receives the post request (Json String) and simply writes it to a log file (for simplicity just making sure I have received it from android app). On the other hand I have an Android app that uses Volley to send a post string request to a mentioned API. I have used a couple of approaches such as using Stringrequest, JsonObject request etc but none of which seemed to work (I get 400 error code). I have tested the API in postman and everything is okay...I'm receiving the posted string in the API post method. Please help me guys or my job is hanging in the balance if I fail to get this task accomplished. Thanks in advance. My code is attached herewith below:

**Web API controller**

```
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // POST: api/test
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/test")]
        public void Post()
        {
            string param = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            EventLogger.writeErrorLog("Posted payload --> " + param)
        }
   }
```

**Android code to send post**

```
private void postDummy() {
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1106/api/test";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JSONObject jsonBodyObj = new JSONObject();

    try{
        jsonBodyObj.put("payload", "XYZ");
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String requestBody = jsonBodyObj.toString();
    Log.d("Json :--> ", requestBody);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
        @Override    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i("Response",String.valueOf(response));
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    }){
        @Override
        public String getBodyContentType() {
            return "application/json";
        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() {
            try {
                return requestBody == null ? null : requestBody.getBytes("utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
                VolleyLog.wtf("Unsupported Encoding while trying to get the bytes of %s using %s",
                        requestBody, "utf-8");
                return null;
            }
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

**Error Log from Android Studio**

```
D/Json :-->: {"payload":"XYZ"}
```

E/Volley: [561] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 400 for http://10.0.2.2:1106/api/test
E/Volley: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjwc4.png) 6.onErrorResponse: Error:

**Postman test result**
[A screenshot for Web API test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjwc4.png)

Answer (score 1):

My case was very similar, C# web API return 400 when i call from android volley (whit custom headers). The solution (in my case) was simple, just i removed "Content-Type" "application/json" and let volley do whatever it do.

My code working:
ANDROID:

```
                try{
                JSONObject postparams = new JSONObject();
                postparams.put("param1", "1");
                postparams.put("param2", "2");
                String URL=sesion.urlAire + "api/adjunto/getArchivo";
                RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
                JsonObjectRequest objectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(
                    Request.Method.POST,
                    URL,
                    postparams,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject  response) {
                            //do something
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            //do something
                        }
                    }
                )
                {
                    @Override
                    public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                        HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                        //headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                        headers.put("authorization", sesion.token);
                        return headers;
                    }
                };
                requestQueue.add(objectRequest);

            }catch (Exception e){}
```

C#:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public CustomObject getArchivo(PostData postData) {
        return new CustomObject{ param1="1" };
    }
```